# the definition of a residue field in a scheme as a functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

We define a functorial scheme as in ["Two functorial definitions of schemes"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177933/two-functorial-definitions-of-schemes). We would like to define a residue field of a scheme. The first idea I came up with was to use a notion of a structure sheaf. As is well known, the one of the way to define a residue field is to use the stalk of a structure sheaf. A structure sheaf can be defined as [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766198/the-definition-of-invertible-sheaf-on-a-functorial-scheme-in-category-theory/3766231#3766231) in a functorial scheme. However, to get the stalk require a set theoretical point, and so we don't know set theoretical points of a functor. This is why we can't get the stalk of a structure sheaf. Can we define the definition of a residue field in a scheme as a functor?

Comment: How does it even make sense to talk about residue fields if you aren't talking about points?  A residue field is the residue field *of a point*.  If you know what the residue fields are in any reasonable sense, you must know what the points are (since they are in canonical bijection with the points).

Comment: Maybe you want to talk about the residue field of a scheme at a $k$-point where $k$ is a field (meaning, the residue field at the set-theoretic point that is the image of that $k$-point)?

Comment: In any case, it's simply not true that "we don't know set theoretical points of a functor".  You can recover the set theoretical points of a scheme defined as a functor if you want to.  Is your goal to specifically avoid doing that?

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you for comments! The answer is yes. Indeed a residue field require a point. But a point of a scheme $X$ is defined as $Hom(Spec(R),X)$ for some ring R, so it's purely category theory. I also would like to define the residue field in purely category theory.

Comment: What does "purely category theory" mean?

Comment: I use "purely category theory" as a meaning of "by using only the concept of category theory."

Comment: Well, I would say that recovering the set-theoretic points of the scheme and then taking the residue field as usual is a perfectly good way to use the concepts of category theory.  Really, what concepts *aren't* concepts of category theory if they are used when studying a category?

Comment: (Not that this is the only or even the best way to define residue fields.  But my point is you need to be clearer about what you are trying to accomplish here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a scheme and $p\in X(k)$ is a $k$-point for some field $k$, you can define the residue field at $p$ as the smallest subfield $k_0\subseteq k$ such that $p$ lifts to a point of $X(k_0)$ (with respect to the inclusion map $k_0\to k$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments! Indeed, Although to strictly define "by using only the concept of category theory" seems so hard, I think it has been achieved by this answer.